# How do I post to a Facebook Page using the Graph API without having my Facebook App reviewed?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook documentation has this page called [Posting as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing) which I've been following.

I followed the instructions on how to obtain an "immortal" access token for the Page.

I've used the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) to check my token is correct. It has the right AppID, the right ProfileID (for the page), and the right UserID (for the owner of the page). It expires "Never", it is valid, and it has the right scopes: `manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions, public_profile`.

I then used the [Facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net/) to make the call to the API to post to the Page.

```
var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

facebookClient.Post(string.Format("{0}/feed", profileID), new
{
    message = message
});
```

The post appears on the Page and if I hover "globe" icon to see it's visibility/accessibility it says "public".

So, it worked right? Well ... no.

It turns out only users assigned a role in the Facebook App can see that post, despite it looking like a normal post and saying it's public. For any other users or those who are not signed in it simply doesn't appear.

The documentation page [Page Access Tokens and Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens) says:

> Your app might not need to request these permissions because people posting are already set up with a role in your app's dashboard. If this is the case you do not need to submit your app for review. See the Roles tab in App Dashboard.

I notice it says "people" which is a touch ambiguous. Does that mean only Users can publish to a Page without being reviewed? You can't publish as the Page itself without the review?

I've tried adding the page to the "Developers" and "Testers" roles for the app using the Pages ProfileID, but it says it can't resolve that to a UserID or name. That makes sense, roles are for people rather than pages.

EDIT 1:

I've tried using the "Embed Post" function and that gave me a link to the post. I tried using the link with a user that can't see the post and got:

[image: Link Error]

It's not expired, as the users that can see it can still see it. It's interesting that it says you might not be in the audience that can view it, but it's set to public which I believe means everyone should see it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with permission review. You need to make your app “live” (see top of Status&Review tab), otherwise content created through it will only be visible to people with a role in the app.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your app “live” (see top of Status&Review tab), otherwise content created through it will only be visible to people with a role in the app.

(This has nothing to do with permission review.)